# Why are pointers to incomplete types allowed and not variables of incomplete types?

Tags: c, typedef, forward-declaration

Why is the following legal:

```
typedef struct a aType;
struct a
{
   int x;
   aType *b;
};
```

and the following illegal:

```
void main()
{
    typedef struct a aType;
    aType someVariable;
    struct a
    {
      int x;
      aType *b;
    };
}
```

I'm just curious as in each case it is forward referencing and as far as I know, at least for functions and variables, forward referencing is not legal.

Also, would the answer for this be the same for C++ as well?

Comment: In case 2, the compiler doesn't know the size of `aType` yet — that appears after you try to define `someVariable`.  You could, however, use `aType *somePointer;` legitimately — the pointer size is known even if the size of what it points to is not.

Comment: See [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Comment: Please use a more corresponding title. It is completely unrelated to what you ask. And if you are interested about different languages, ask seperate questions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Function main can have any type in a hosted environment.

Comment: @2501: And what makes you think I don't know that?  I didn't say it was wrong — I pointed to where there is information about the return type of `main()`.  If the code is not running on Windows, using `void main()` is very unlikely to be correct, though.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Isn't it theoretically possible to have a different pointer sizes to different types?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Yes, but pointers to all `struct` types will have the same size and representation (6.2.5/28).

Comment: @JohnBode Thanks. I've suspected this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This of it this way:

```
typedef struct a aType;
struct a { int x; aType *b; };
```

is the same as:

```
struct a;
typedef struct a aType;
struct a { int x; aType *b; };
```

So you're forward-declaring a `struct`, `typedef`ing it and later defining it. Perfectly fine.

Now the second example:

```
typedef struct a aType;
aType someVariable;
struct a { int x; aType *b; };
```

This has nothing to do with the fact that it's in local scope.
What's happening is this:

```
struct a;
typedef struct a aType;
aType someVariable; // error: when it gets here, aType is still incomplete
struct a { int x; aType *b; };
aType someVariable; // perfectly fine, aType not incomplete
```

Remember that compilation happens in order. When you try to declare `someVariable` the compiler doesn't know what `struct a` is yet, so it doesn't know its size, hence it doesn't know how much memory to allocate for it, hence a compile error. Declaring it after `aType` is defined works as expected.

Answer (score 6):

You are allowed to create pointers to incomplete types, because the size of the pointer object does not depend on the size of the pointed-to type.  Pointers to different `struct` types have the same size and representation, regardless of the size of the `struct` type itself.

You are not allowed to create *instances* of incomplete types, since the size of the type isn't known.

Comment: [Your citation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41751479/why-are-pointers-to-incomplete-types-allowed-and-not-variables-of-incomplete-typ#comment70698059_41751479) is also useful.